# XLayout cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, layout-manager

I was going through a java book on GUI Basics and on one of the lines it has me do,

`LayoutManager layoutManager = new XLayout();`

I've got `import java.awt.*;` and `import java.swing.*;` and it's still complaining that it's not a type. I've looked around a few places, but I can't find any references to it other than in some programming books written out the same way I have it above. The part I'm working on is dealing with "Layout Managers."

Comment: XLayout is not a standard java class - it may be a custom class that is detailed somewhere else in your book.

Comment: @assylias, I don't believe that to be true as I have an electronic version of the book and searching through it doesn't return anything else with XLayout.

Book: 
Introduction to Java Programming
Comprehensive Version
Ninth Edition
Y. Daniel Liang

Comment: I don't know about the book but XLayout does not exist in the JDK... This is the only thing I could find on Google: http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t87864.html - not sure if that is what you are looking for. Maybe the book comes with a CD of examples that contain that class?